# Animate a child element as well as the parent

Tags: html, css, css-animations

**The problem**

I have two elements: an animated square and arrow (static).
I want to start to move the arrow, too, and the arrow has always been in the middle of the right-hand side of the square. Is there a way to do it only by using css? And, furthermore, if this is possible without code duplication animation of the square, to which add some offset? I tried to think of :after, :nth-child, set the arrow as child element of the square with absolute/relative position, but I have not reached the goal.

**Example of Square css**

```
.animated-square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

**Example of arrow css**

```
.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #18ff08;
  border: 3px solid #0aff3b; 
  width:30px;
}

.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(24, 255, 8, 0);
  border-left-color: #18ff08;
  border-width: 4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(10, 255, 59, 0);
  border-left-color: #0aff3b;
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle example of two types of elements](http://jsfiddle.net/Malinchyn/enw33x2o/3/)

The below image shows the relative position of the desired square and arrows in the animation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting the arrow within the square would be the most obvious solution...

```css
/*animation*/
.animated-square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}


/*arrow*/
.arrow_box {
  position: absolute;
  background: #18ff08;
  border: 3px solid #0aff3b; 
  width:30px;
 right: -36px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(24, 255, 8, 0);
  border-left-color: #18ff08;
  border-width: 4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(10, 255, 59, 0);
  border-left-color: #0aff3b;
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-square">
    <div class="arrow_box"></div>
</div>
```